# IOS monogame 17 seconds debug timeout

Tags: ios, monogame, mono, monotouch

I'm trying to debug a monogame application using xamarin studio and breakpoint.
Is it possible to disable the 17 seconds timeout on the FinishedLaunching function?

Comment: Isn't the real question.. why does it takes 17 seconds to launch?

Comment: Well it's not that it takes 17 seconds to launch, i'm just trying to debbug it with a breakpoint and after 17 seconds it timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

What you can do is to add a timer for whatever you want to debug so that it happens after FinishedLaunching has completed.